# What is the shortcut for closing chrome Inspect?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using mac.
I know that using "cmd+shift+c" can open the Inspect. But is there a shortcut for closing Inspect?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts?hl=en

Comment: cmd-alt-J closes the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Command+Option+I seems to open and close the inspect window.